# Contents of table are not aligned left

Tags: html, css

I want the `<img>` and `Test` to be aligned left, but they aren't.

My code:

```
<center>
  <div class="body" id="block">
    <span style="width:95%;background-color: rgb(247,247,247);border-radius:10px;display:block;">
      <table>
        <tr style="height:25px;">
          <td style="width:70%;margin-left:10px;font-size:20px;text-align:left;display:block;">
            <img style="height:20px;" src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2i9qzj5.png">
            Test
          </td>
          <td style="font-size:12px;">
            Another test
          </td>
          <td style="width:5%;">
          </td>
          <td style="width:15%;font-size:12px;">
            Third test
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </span>
  </div>
</center>
```

I've tried several things, but still does not work.
I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: First thing don't use table tag in span. When i check your code table show properly in center.

Comment: I want the img and "Test" to be aligned left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove CSS `display:block` of `<td>` tag:

```
<td style="width:70%;margin-left:10px;font-size:20px;text-align:left;display:block;">
```

New code:

```
<td style="width:70%;margin-left:10px;font-size:20px;text-align:left;">
```

By default, `<td>` in table has CSS:  `display: table-cell;`

**True answer:**

```
 table { width: 100%; }
```

Comment: img and 'test' are still in center, I want them to be left.

Comment: I see they are left. Or I don't see your option. Can you explain detail?

Comment: You can add css: table {
    width: 100%;
}

Comment: That helped, Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

It's still messed up, but i don't clean the code.

```html
<center>
  <div class="body" id="block">
    <div style="width:95%;background-color: rgb(247,247,247);border-radius:10px;">
      <table style="width: 100%">
        <tr style="height:25px;">
          <td style="width:70%;padding-left: 10px;font-size:20px;text-align:left;">
            <img style="height:20px;" src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2i9qzj5.png">
            Test
          </td>
          <td style="font-size:12px;">
            Another test
          </td>
          <td style="width:5%;">
          </td>
          <td style="width:15%;font-size:12px;">
            Third test
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</center>
```

Comment: img and 'test'are still in center, I want them to be left.

Answer (score -1):

Hey this is my first post, but I hope I can help you with my answer. I pulled out the css from your html and also switched to div's, something I would recommend you do.

HTML:

```
<center>
  <div class="body" id="block">

     <div class="user item">
       <img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2i9qzj5.png">
       Test
     </div>
     <div class="title item">
       Another Test
     </div>
     <div class="third item">
       Third test
     </div>

  </div>
</center>
```

CSS:

```
.body {
  width:100%;
  height:25px;
  background-color: rgb(247,247,247);
  border-radius:10px;
  display:block;
}

.item {
  width:20%;
  display:inline-block;
}

.user {
  float:left;
  font-size:20px;
}

.user img {
  height:20px;
}

.title {
  font-size:12px;
}

.third {
}

.td4 {
  font-size:12px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tatimblin/n7kunmo2/)

Comment: If I'd like to use divs, I would've already be using them here.